# How to load application from sectors?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I'm creating custom MBR that have to load application stored in next 32 sectors, everything works except loading application and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, so if someone knows what and how to fix it, please help me.

**[Victoria.asm](https://github.com/WobbyChip/Assembly/tree/master/Victoria)**

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

Kernel:
    ;---Setup Segments
    xor ax, ax               ;AX=0
    mov ds, ax               ;DS=ES=0 because we use an org of 0x7c00 - Segment<<4+offset = 0x0000<<4+0x7c00 = 0x07c00
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00           ;SS:SP= 0x0000:0x7c00 stack just below bootloader

    ;---Read Kernel
    mov bx, buffer           ;ES: BX must point to the buffer
    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl     ;save the boot drive
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]     ;use boot drive passed to bootloader by BIOS in DL
    mov dh,0                 ;head number
    mov ch,0                 ;track number
    mov cl,2                 ;sector number
    mov al,128               ;number of sectors to read
    mov ah,2                 ;read function number
    int 13h

    ;---Start Application
    jmp buffer

;Fake MBR Signature
BOOT_DRIVE: db 0
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

;Victoria Freeware - The Kernel
victoria: incbin "Victoria.com"
times 65536 - ($ - $$) db 0

;Buffer
buffer:
```

Comment: Well, the first thing that jumps out at me is setting the segments.  You do `mov sp, 0x7c00`, which you say moves 0x7c00 to sp.  But you also do `mov ax, ds` and you expect this to move ax to ds?  Which way do you think the `mov` moves? You also never say exactly what is going wrong.  Don't force us to run your code to try to understand your problem.

Comment: You put `buffer:` in the wrong place. It should be after `dw 0xAA55`

Comment: interesting but, it doesn't work, nothing changed

Comment: I can tell you this, disassembling victoria.com (the binary) its not going to get far. I'm not sure where you got that code from but it won't run as expected even if it was loaded into memory. The code looks good for loading but I don't think it is at all running victoria.com the way you expect.

Comment: This code is correct if you place `buffer:` after the line `dw 0xAA55`. The problem is that `Victoria.com` doesn't contain code that will run properly the way it has been loaded.

Comment: The file seems to be a compressed Free-DOS UPX file. Looking at the uncompressed code it relies on `int 0x21` DOS interrupts which aren't even available to a bootloader.

Comment: Okay, I decompressed it and now it's size is 56kb, and remember that segment limit is 65536 bytes, but after everything I did, it's still doesn't work, just black screen.

Comment: That program is a DOS COM program, it will not run in a bootloader. Where did you get Victoria.com? You can't just run arbitrary DOS programs when DOS isn't available.How do you expect the DOS calls in Victoria.com to run when DOS isn't even loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that when you call `int 0x13, ah = 0x02` you need the device number for the device you want to read from in `dl`. The device number you booted from is given to you by the BIOS in `dl`, but the code overwrites this (the previous `mov dx, 0x184F`) so you're asking to read data from a completely different device (that probably doesn't exist).

There are multiple other issues. The segment registers aren't set up correctly (e.g. `mov ax,ds` instead of `mov ds,ax`) and aren't set up in the right place (should be done before segments are used - e.g. before the `ds` segment is used by the `mov al,[si]` instruction in the code to print a string). You can't just assume that `int 0x13, ah = 0x02` worked without checking for error (and if there's an error you should display nice "end user readable" error message/s that give the user some hope of figuring out what they can do to fix the problem).

Finally there's a conceptual issue. For partitioned devices (hard drives, USB flash, etc) the main thing the MBR should do is start an operating system's boot loader from the active partition (MBR shouldn't be considered part of any specific operating system, the operating system's boot code begins with the 1st sector of the operating system's partition). For unpartitioned devices (floppy disks) you need a BPB (BIOS Parameter Block) for various reasons (so that other operating systems don't think the disk is unformatted, and so that the BIOS thinks it's valid for various special cases like "USB flash emulating floppy" and "bootable CD emulating floppy").

**UPDATE**

Yeah, the question is morphing and some of the answer above no longer applies. The current problems are:

- `ds` not set before it's used by the `mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl` instruction that uses it
- `mov ax,cs` can't be right. When the BIOS starts the code it can do a `jmp 0x0000:0x7C00` or a `jmp 0x07C0:0x0000` (or any combination) so `cs` isn't set to a known value and loading an unknown value into `ax` won't help much.
- `mov ax,ds` (immediately after the `mov ax,cs`) doesn't set `ds` but loads `ax` with the value that the BIOS happened to leave in `ds`. I think this instruction was supposed to be a `mov ds,ax` (which might or might not have worked, depending on which computer/BIOS is being used)
- `mov ax, ds`, `mov ax, es`, and `mov ax, ss` (immediately after the `kernel:` label) have the same problem (should be `mov ds, ax`, `mov es, ax`, and `mov ss, ax`